# Group by on Varchar field messing up

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, group-by, common-table-expression

I have the below table data in my project. The table is partitioned with row number.

[image: Available data table]

In this table, the rownumber 1 represents courses taken by the student in first quarter. Similarly rownumber 2 represents second quarter courses. same as row numbers 3 and 4. I want to pull out the overall list of courses and grade . Grade for the courses should be the grade of the last time that course was taken. So, the result data table should be as below:

[image: Expected result table]

I have written the below group by query:

```
SELECT
    T.NAME,
    T.COURSE,
    T.HRSCODE,
    MAX(T.GRADE) as 'GRADE'
FROM 
    #TEMP T 
GROUP BY 
    T.NAME, T.COURSE, T.HRSCODE
```

Demo: rextester.com/FSUIM64308

`MAX(grade)` is returning wrong grades for subject 'Math'. Is there any other way to accomplish the result?

Comment: how did you generate the row_number?

Comment: I see no relationship between your desired results and the input data.

Comment: Row_number is generated with Partition.

Comment: jump to `sqlfiddle.com` or `rextester.com` to muck up a data

Comment: I want to pull out distinct courses taken by student across quarters. And their grades are the grades earned by the student @last time when the course was taken. Makes sense?

Comment: http://rextester.com/FSUIM64308 -- demo

Comment: where is the year?

Comment: Missed year. Now added it. http://rextester.com/KWGG17431

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a classic top-n-per-group problem.

One way to do it is by using the `ROW_NUMBER` function.

**Sample data**

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP1(ROWNUM INT,
NAME VARCHAR(50), COURSE VARCHAR(50), year int,
CAT VARCHAR(50), HRSCODE VARCHAR(30), GRADE VARCHAR(10))

insert TEMP1 values
    ('1' ,  'STUDENT1' ,    'MATH       ' , 2016,'CRS1' ,'MT1.Y7'  , 'A+'),
    ('1' ,  'STUDENT1' ,    'ENGLISH    ' , 2016,'CRS2' ,'ENG14.JI', 'B'),
    ('1' ,  'STUDENT1' ,    'SCIENCE    ' , 2016,'CRS3' ,'SCI678'  , 'C'),
    ('1' ,  'STUDENT1' ,    'HISTORY    ' , 2016,'CRS4' ,'HIS704'  , 'A+'),
    ('2' ,  'STUDENT1' ,    'MATH       ' , 2016,'CRS1' ,'MT1.Y7'  , 'A-'),
    ('2' ,  'STUDENT1' ,    'ENGLISH    ' , 2016,'CRS2' ,'ENG14.JI', 'B+'),
    ('2' ,  'STUDENT1' ,    'SCIENCE    ' , 2016,'CRS3' ,'SCI678'  , 'C+'),
    ('2' ,  'STUDENT1' ,    'HISTORY    ' , 2016,'CRS4' ,'HIS704'  , 'C-'),
    ('3' ,  'STUDENT1' ,    'MATH       ' , 2017,'CRS1' ,'MT1.Y7'  , 'A+'),
    ('3' ,  'STUDENT1' ,    'ENGLISH    ' , 2017,'CRS2' ,'ENG14.JI', 'A+'),
    ('3' ,  'STUDENT1' ,    'PSYCHOLOGY ' , 2017,'CRS3' ,'PSY9.78' , 'B'),
    ('3' ,  'STUDENT1' ,    'PHYSICS    ' , 2017,'CRS4' ,'PHY53.XG', 'B'),
    ('4' ,  'STUDENT1' ,    'MATH       ' , 2017,'CRS1' ,'MT1.Y7'  , 'A'),
    ('4' ,  'STUDENT1' ,    'ENGLISH    ' , 2017,'CRS2' ,'ENG14.JI', 'C'),
    ('4' ,  'STUDENT1' ,    'PSYCHOLOGY ' , 2017,'CRS3' ,'PSY9.78' , 'B'),
    ('4' ,  'STUDENT1' ,    'PHYSICS    ' , 2017,'CRS4' ,'PHY53.XG', 'C+');
```

Please note, that your original sample data in rextester had tabs in the names of the courses and I replaced it with spaces.

**Query**

```
SELECT TOP(1) WITH TIES
    NAME
    ,COURSE
    ,year
    ,CAT
    ,HRSCODE
    ,GRADE
FROM TEMP1
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NAME, COURSE ORDER BY year DESC,  ROWNUM DESC)
;
```

http://rextester.com/edit/KQKP45357

**Result**

```
+----+----------+-------------+------+------+----------+-------+
|    |   NAME   |   COURSE    | year | CAT  | HRSCODE  | GRADE |
+----+----------+-------------+------+------+----------+-------+
|  1 | STUDENT1 | ENGLISH     | 2017 | CRS2 | ENG14.JI | C     |
|  2 | STUDENT1 | MATH        | 2017 | CRS1 | MT1.Y7   | A     |
|  3 | STUDENT1 | HISTORY     | 2016 | CRS4 | HIS704   | C-    |
|  4 | STUDENT1 | PHYSICS     | 2017 | CRS4 | PHY53.XG | C+    |
|  5 | STUDENT1 | PSYCHOLOGY  | 2017 | CRS3 | PSY9.78  | B     |
|  6 | STUDENT1 | SCIENCE     | 2016 | CRS3 | SCI678   | C+    |
+----+----------+-------------+------+------+----------+-------+
```

The more common way to write this query is like this:

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        ROWNUM
        ,NAME
        ,COURSE
        ,year
        ,CAT
        ,HRSCODE
        ,GRADE
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY NAME, COURSE ORDER BY year DESC, ROWNUM DESC) AS rn
    FROM TEMP1
)
SELECT
    NAME
    ,COURSE
    ,year
    ,CAT
    ,HRSCODE
    ,GRADE
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY NAME, COURSE
;
```

Comment: Wowww this is exactly what I wanted. Thanks!!

Comment: You are welcome. If you want to learn other approaches with comparison and a lot of details, have a look at this question: [Retrieving n rows per group](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/86415/57105)

Answer (score 0):

Your current query is meant to list the highest grades and not the latest ones.

If you want to get the latest grades for the student, you shouldn't use Max() which chooses the highest value.

As I can see your ROWNUM might help you to get a chronogical order in your courses, so I suggest you to list one line for each subject having their highest value on ROWNUM.

For example, if we look at history, which is last recorded on ROWNUM 2, then its highest chronogical value would be 2 (while Math's would be 4). Then you can display, as a final result, the grades of History from ROWNUM 2, Math from ROWNUM 4 and so on. That way you will get the latest grades only.

P.S : this only works if you don't have two same subjects for one ROWNUM, so it might not be the best solution for further table changes.

Comment: Can you demo this in fiddler?

Comment: @Rick I've never used fiddler so I used your previous SQL tool to show what I meant : http://rextester.com/WTBKJ25044

Comment: Also, I've found that you put tabulations inside the VARCHAR delimiters, which caused your other varchars 'math     ' to be different than your first 'math', this one containing no tabulation. You don't have to add any, since the varchar will manage the length on its own.